# How to determine the distribution and expected value of $X$?

Tags: probability

6 girls and 4 boys are taking part in a competition. There are no ties and all permutations are equally probable. Let $X$ be the place of the girl with the highest score ( e. g. if $X=1$ means the winner is a girl). How to determine the distribution and expected value of $X$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

Use 1 to represent a girl in the ranking and 0 to represent a boy. So a ranking can be written as a string of 1's and 0's.

For $X=5$, the string is 0000111111 and there is only one arrangement. For $X=4$, there are $^7C_1$ arrangements. For $X=3$, there are $^8C_2$ arrangements, etc.

Can you complete from here?